# How can a customer choose between different format of digital products

Tags: downloadable, extensions

We have two different websites that sells maps in different file format. Is there a ways or is there an extension where a customer can download a file according to their requirement on just one website.

Is there a way where we can upload different file format of a single map and sell that to the customer. It will also be easier to the customer where they can choose the file format that they want and buy it.

Answer (score 1):

In the downloadable information of the product, you can add multiple links. If you set **Links can be purchased separately** to yes, your customers can choose which file formats they want to buy.

Tutorial with detailed information can be found here: http://www.solvingmagento.com/magento-downloadable-product-type-part-1/